# Understanding long term behavior of a sequence of partial sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppse $(a_{n})$ is a decreasing sequence of numbers and we have the series $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} n(a_{n}-a_{n+1}).$$
If we start to write out the sequence of partial sums $(S_{m})$, we get that $S_{m} = \sum_{n=1}^{m} a_{n} - m\cdot a_{m+1}$. I want to conclude $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} n(a_{n}-a_{n+1})=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_{n}.$$ From the looks of $S_{m}$, I am *almost* there. If that last term wasn't there and I took the limit as $M \rightarrow \infty$, I'd be good to go! But the last term is tripping me up. I know that it will be gone if I add the next term of the series (and this can be done repeatedly). But, I am not quite alright with that. Any help/explanation?

Comment: You can only conclude that if $m\cdot a_{m+1}\to 0$ as $m\to\infty$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 But then both sums diverge, so the limits are the same in that case.

Comment: @esip7, Do you know if $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_{n}$ converge ?

Comment: No. Actually, I may not even have $a_n \rightarrow 0$. (This is in the midst of a large problem.) The statement $\sum n(a_{n}-a_{n+1}) = \sum a_{n}$ appeared out of nowhere (as if by magic). I checked the sequence of partial sums and ran into the problem above. I am trying to find additional condition that are placed on the sequence that would make it so. I only have $(a_{n})$ decreases--not necesarrily to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

A very partial answer.

If $ma_{m+1}\to 0$ you are correct.

It is also true if $\liminf ma_{m+1}>0$ since then both series diverge.

Obviously, if $\liminf ma_{m+1}\neq 0$ then the sequence also diverges.

So, what happens when $\liminf ma_{m+1}=0$ but $\lim ma_{m+1}$ does not exist?

Comment: What if I *only* have that $a_{n} \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on decreasing first.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $a_n$ is decreasing and goes to $0$. Hence $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n$.

We have as you have shown that
$$S_m=\sum_{n=1}^{m}n(a_n-a_{n+1})=(\sum_{n=1}^m a_n)-ma_{m+1}$$

Suppose first that $\displaystyle T_m=\sum_{n=1}^m a_n$ is convergent, say to $T$. As $S_m\leq T_m$, we have then that $S_m$ is convergent, say to $S$. Thus the sequence $ma_{m+1}$ is convergent. But if its limit $L$ is $>0$, this imply that $\displaystyle a_m\sim \frac{L}{m}$, and $\displaystyle \sum a_n$ is divergent, a contradiction. Hence $ma_m \to 0$, and $S=T$.

Now suppose that $S_m$ is convergent, to $S$. We have then $S_m\leq S$ for all $m$, hence $$a_1+\cdots+a_m\leq S+ma_{m+1}\leq S+ma_m$$
Let $p\geq 1$. We have also
$$a_1+\cdots+a_m+a_{m+1}+\cdots a_{m+p}\leq S+(m+p)a_{m+p}=S+ ma_{m+p}+pa_{m+p}$$
and

$$pa_{m+p}\leq a_{m+1}+\cdots+a_{m+p}$$

Thus
$$a_1+\cdots+a_{m}\leq S+ma_{m+p}$$

If $p\to \infty$, $ma_{m+p}\to 0$, and hence $\displaystyle a_1+\cdots+a_{m}\leq S$, and the series $\displaystyle \sum a_m$ is convergent. By the first step, we have $S=T$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a_n$ is decreasing and $\sum_n a_n$ converges. For any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is 
$N$ such that $\sum_{n \ge N} a_n < \varepsilon$.  For any $m > 2N$ we then have
$$\varepsilon > \sum_{n=N}^m a_n > \sum_{n=N}^m a_m > \dfrac{m a_m}{2}$$
Thus $m a_m \to 0$.